# Updating FCM Token on Flutter App

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token, refresh, flutter

I have a Flutter app that creates a FCM Token on the first run, like this:

```
_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
  //save my token here
});
```

However, I understand that this token can be refreshed once in awhile. In order to get this new refreshed token, I must call `onTokenRefresh` method:

```
Stream<String> fcmStream = _firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh;
fcmStream.listen((token) {
  saveToken(token);
});
```

The problem is that I don't know if this it is correct. The line `saveToken(token)` is always execute when the app runs, but it works when the app is not on foreground/background?

I mean, this `onTokenRefresh` will keep listening even if the user closes the app?

If not, how do I get the new token if the app doesn't get started for a long time?

Comment: Are you sure that the generated token wouldn't be changed later. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 21):

Base on [this firebase document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) fcm token will changed on below events:

- The app deletes Instance ID
- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data

If the app doesn't get started for a long time, and none of the above events has occurred, the app token will not changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the documentation says that, then I have nothing to worry about.